Как определить, что сайт является сайтом-прокладкой(подложкой)?
Есть сайт А, который отправляется запросы через сайт Б на сайт С. Т.е сайт Б является прокладкой между А и С. При это изначально сайт С не знает о существовании сайта А. Каким образом можно выявить, что сайт Б является сайтом-прокладкой? Что запросы изначально приходит от А, а не от Б? Возможно есть какие-то инструменты, сервисы для этого? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Тоесть сервер Б - проксирующий.. ну.. сервер C определит что IP ресурса не принадлежит А.. Вот как бы и все) а так проксируйте сколько угодно

Не совсем так, сайт А отправляет api запрос на Б, сайт Б пересобирает запрос(добавляет параметры, создает новый хедер) и отправляет на С

Если все заголовки от А передаются через В в С, то никак, обычно определяют по User-Agent (и других заголовкам) и данным в них о вероятной операционной системе, определяя если это сервер или десктоп.

@Daniel Protopopov, я Вас правильно понял, что если заголовки поменялись, то уже никак не узнать?

По сути вы описали MITM (Man-in-the-middle) атаку, смотрите варианты её решения в Интернете. SSL это частично решает, но не всегда, а про текстовые данные в запросе и говорить нечего - по ним можно только косвенно и не 100% определить такие вещи.
